# ReactJS fetch post API 405 issue

Tags: json, reactjs, post, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am using swagger to post APi which works fine, but when I post it from react jsm that cause 405 issue.
Fiddler appears the RAW information for swagger as following:

```
POST http://localhost:7100/api/test/submit?guid=17327026-4348-4ce9-aceb-5774c3a724bf HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7100
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 14
Origin: http://localhost:7100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:7100/swagger/ui/index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=yzdydpdimqvgpvejykzjqqqb; .ASPXAUTH=dWLGc_XQvl3qTNrEJXsRyk3w-tXBSFeXKC0bIUDzLDLFJi5kbSAt_hcJXQs0-pfz7uVm-VJ27ZGAbN8eErCNV-Wozn3D1ZbHD7ONNN5VCMjT_Joyz_1aIcTZLR401s0TtC4Br1sRlerv0zX4F4xnDLhrIm5YKkGfZj2aZzDgc-KjNPVWY1SEC6k2XqPq54vo9_HUvudihHGlneNx1n2JlodvFxAeYudKnUSBRWpp2rRAx94uF7KmmP5BQoTmBTTq1qKSv98YiPToicePFR32d9yk1Uw1qcFrnkKD2zKOCuJByNgCLN_eC5dOmdLKfPCekciEJ16KfeYg8XeApIf13vCrtGOy-L2EXibWuEjUjKCrUy8sfYTGNZbxDffTg9gNOn7-nfyR5hKLYDM0CxfmENV7S0ExTSFyGhsR5aqqB3oXq3A_i8ENabgGMy_tFyor06S7_vrUUcDlS2hFgsxWzgMrRUdVIlohHK2-slPdbhwuUKIZXKKiSQijwH0RskwF-l8RyVe_0VCcCVipk4MXtncDvrubmEW09LWeOycyc0wc1BmMHL9AATpBHA6WBNLEaMGS9-x-RhFC5YNJW1KtetmlXiaKmiX9L-2wWhVRgjlhmfjtRPjxlVvW1GxyeKC-JOlSPnY6DInNM-qa2dcZjdaoffdnLBvzKTHkJNwzUSZw8fN-Vz6SVmURMtpEQAKmxloNvw

"test working"
```

for post from react as following:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:7100/api/test/submit?guid=17327026-4348-4CE9-ACEB-5774C3A724BF HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7100
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/?testId=17327026-4348-4ce9-aceb-5774c3a724bf
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.8,zh;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.4
```

I believe something wrong in following fetch post function, is there any chance to fix it, then the RAW information can be same as first one.

```
onFormSubmit(Result) {
     fetch("http://localhost:7100/api/test/submit?guid=" +  "17327026-4348-4CE9-ACEB-5774C3A724BF",
      { 
        method: 'POST',
      // headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
     headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, 
   //     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      //  body: JSON.stringify(result) 
      body: "test working"
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.ok ? 'success' : 'error');
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('catch error');
      });
  }
```

Comment: The issue was with Cors issue, update Http Put instead of Post, FYI http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [CORS](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) Issue You need to allow requests comming from http://localhost:3000 in you server.

Comment: A REST Client such as Swager don't care if the server allows it to communicate with it  but web browsers like Chrome will verify that the origin is allowed by the server, this is done by sending a OPTIONS request before your POST request and the server have to respond with status 200 for it.

Comment: not clear to this, it works on swagger, so there must be issue on post when fetch it in react? @Akram

Comment: Can you tell what is printed in the javascript console ?

Comment: OPTIONS http://localhost:7100/api/test/submit?guid=17327026-4348-4CE9-ACEB-5774C3A724BF 405 (Method Not Allowed)

localhost/:1 Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:7100/api/test/submit?guid=17327026-4348-4CE9-ACEB-5774C3A724BF. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: So what i said was true, the server is responding you by code 405 Method not allowed, When web browser asks the server if he can send him a POST request (which is done by the OPTIONS request) the server replies NO (405)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150208/discussion-between-user2235768-and-akram-mecheri).